# WebRTC and Socket.io (not sending messages)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc

I have the following code, and my problem is that socket.io is not sending messages... Any ideas?

I've tried .emit('broadcast','test') with no success. After getting the user media I'm sending a message for testing purposes, openning two tabs with the same code, none of the tabs get the message.

I've read some posts telling that I should broadcast the message instead of sending through the current socket. But I'm unable to use io.sockets.send() method for this purpose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebRTC Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var localVideo;
        var remoteVideo;
        var peerConnection;
        var uuid;
        var serverConnection;
        var localStream;

        var peerConnectionConfig = {
            'iceServers': [
                {'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
                {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
            ]
        };

        window.addEventListener('load', pageReady);

        function pageReady() {
            uuid = uuid();

            localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
            remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

            serverConnection = io.connect('https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443');

            serverConnection.on('message', gotMessageFromServer);

            var constraints = {
                video: true,
                audio: true
            };

            if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(getUserMediaSuccess).catch(errorHandler);
            } else {
                alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
            }
        }

        function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
            localStream = stream;
            localVideo.srcObject = stream;
            serverConnection.send('test');
        }

        function start(isCaller) {
            peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
            peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
            peerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
            peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

            if(isCaller) {
                peerConnection.createOffer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
            }
        }

        function gotMessageFromServer(message) {
            console.log('Got message', message);
            if(!peerConnection) start(false);

            var signal = JSON.parse(message.data);

            // Ignore messages from ourself
            if(signal.uuid === uuid) return;

            if(signal.sdp) {
                peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp)).then(function() {
                    // Only create answers in response to offers
                    if(signal.sdp.type === 'offer') {
                        peerConnection.createAnswer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
                    }
                }).catch(errorHandler);
            } else if(signal.ice) {
                peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice)).catch(errorHandler);
            }
        }

        function gotIceCandidate(event) {
            if(event.candidate !== null) {
                serverConnection.send({'ice': event.candidate, 'uuid': uuid});
            }
        }

        function createdDescription(description) {
            console.log('got description');

            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description).then(function() {
                console.log("Sending SDP:", description);
                serverConnection.emit('sdp', {'sdp': peerConnection.localDescription, 'uuid': uuid});
            }).catch(errorHandler);
        }

        function gotRemoteStream(event) {
            console.log('got remote stream');
            remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
        }

        function errorHandler(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        function uuid() {
            function s4() {
                return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
            }

            return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Service is up

    <video id="localVideo" autoplay></video>
    <a href="javascript:start(true)">Start call</a>
    <video id="remoteVideo"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any console errors in the output?

Comment: What is the URL of the page this code is in?  Is it on the same server that you are trying to connect to with socket.io?  Can you show us the server-side socket.io code where you are sending the message on the server (whole context)?  Do you get any logging in the `connection` message on the server?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using a external socket server that is working for other applications https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443

Comment: @cramopy no console errors... I've logged when it sends the message and shows no errors

Comment: And, are you 100% sure that the external socket.io server is configured for cross origin access from your page's domain?  That's why I asked what the page URL is (which you did not answer).  While the browser does not enforce cross origin security with a webSocket connection, an ordinary socket.io connection first uses several http polling requests where cross origin security IS enforced.  On your server, are you seeing the client connect?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm running at localhost and the socket.io server is configured with cross origin *. It's from Muaz Khan RTC Experiment

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't showing us the server-side socket.io code?  We're kind of flying half blind here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. I don't have it. I got the server URL from http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/getting-started/ It works with other demos at localhost.

Comment: Your link does not appear to show any code that does an `io.connect()`.  I don't know where you're getting your socket.io client code from.  [This reference](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectsocket) seems to show a different way of connecting.